# How to turn vector with quotation marks into values in square brackets with apostrophes?

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector `c("john", "mike")`. I want to turn it into `('john', 'mike')`. How could I do that?

Comment: So then it'll be reduced to a single element!! will that be ok.  Try `paste`

Comment: no, paste doesn't work. i need it to be in that format, so i can paste it in sql_glue()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> paste0("(", toString(sprintf("'%s'", v)), ")")
[1] "('john', 'mike')"
```

or

```
> sprintf("(%s)", toString(gsub("(.*)", "'\\1'", v)))
[1] "('john', 'mike')"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to convert anything.

```
tbl<-"table1"
glue_sql("SELECT * FROM {`tbl`} WHERE name IN ({names*})",
names = c("john", "mike"), .con = con)
# SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE name IN ('john', 'mike')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think `paste` with `collapse=` has been showcased:

```r
paste0(
    "('",
    paste0( c("john", "mike"),  collapse="', '" ),
    "')"
)
```

```
> paste0(
+     "('",
+     paste0( c("john", "mike"),  collapse="', '" ),
+     "')"
+ )
[1] "('john', 'mike')"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v <- c("john", "mike")
paste0("(", Reduce(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ", "), v), ")")

[1] "(john, mike)"
```

OR

```
v <- c("john", "mike")
paste0("(", Reduce(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ", "), paste0("'", v, "'")), ")")
[1] "('john', 'mike')"
```